# ¿Cómo superponer ventana a todo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Quiero recrear un teclado virtual. he usado tkinter y pyautogui, pero no se como mantener la interfaz grafica superpuesta a todas las otras aplicaciones incluso si les hago click.

Como puedo mantener una interfaz grafica generada por tkinter siempre abierta y sobrepuesta a todas las otras aplicaciones tales como chrome o carpetas?

La idea es imitar al teclado en pantalla de windows el cual siempre esta sobrepuesto a todo y si hago click en otra ventana, el teclado en pantalla persiste sobre puesto a todo.

```
from tkinter import * 
import pyautogui

def escribir(letra):
    pyautogui.press(letra)
    print(letra )

def teclas():
    teclaQ = Button(raiz, text = 'Q', command=lambda:escribir( 'Q'), width = 5, height = 3)
    teclaQ.grid( row = 1, column= 0 )

def gui():
    global raiz

    raiz = Tk()
    raiz.geometry("800x300" )

    teclas()
    e = Entry( raiz,  width=50)
    e.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "we")

    raiz.mainloop()

gui()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que esto debería funcionar en Windows. Linux y MacOS:

```py
# Python3
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True) # Esta es la línea importante.
root.mainloop()
```

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wm+attributes

Comment: Funciona. Ahora quiero que al presionar un widget boton, tal como lo tengo en el codigo, el pyautogui.press(letra) escriba donde sea que tenga el cursor especialmente fuera de la interfaz grafica

Comment: Abre una nueva pregunta, muestra el código que has intentando para lograr lo que quieres y los errores que te estás encontrando.